# Selecting individuals on right hand side of property in class expression

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, manchester-syntax

Couldn't find an answer to my question:
Let's say I have a property "has" and two individuals of different classes A and B.
We define that individual A "has" B.
The individual B doesn't have any information that it is defined as a target of the property "has" by A.
How can define a class that captures all individuals on the right hand side of "has"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe my question wasn't very precise, I didn't know how to put it any other way. What I was looking for:
I realised that in Protege I could just define that this new class should be equivalent to

```
inverse (has) some A
```